# MySQL DbConnection

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, visual-studio-2012, mysql.data

I'm getting a set of errors that I don't know how to reconcile. I'm using EntityFramework5 as that is the latest supported version of EF for MySql.Data & MySql.Data.Entity. It is App.Config that is throwing the errors. Here are the two alternations I have been trying and have no solution for.

```
   <entityFramework>
     <defaultConnectionFactory type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data" />
     <providers>
       <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"
                type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity" />
     </providers>
   </entityFramework>
```

**In this example I get the error:** `{"Unrecognized element 'providers'. (C:\\Users\\recursor\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2012\\Projects\\CS3280\\Final Project\\IR\\ConsoleApplication2\\bin\\Debug\\ConsoleApplication2.vshost.exe.Config line 16)"}`

From what I understand providers is not supported in EF5 so I have tried using this.

```
   <entityFramework>
     <defaultConnectionFactory type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data" />
     <contexts>
       <context type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity" />
     </contexts>
   </entityFramework>
```

**In this example I get the error:** `{"Required attribute 'invariant' not found. (C:\\Users\\recursor\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2012\\Projects\\CS3280\\Final Project\\IR\\ConsoleApplication2\\bin\\Debug\\ConsoleApplication2.vshost.exe.Config line 34)"}`

I tried putting invariant in and get a warning The 'invariantName' attribute is not allowed (nor is invariant).

**If I put invariant in, it gets this error:** `{"Required attribute 'invariant' not found. (C:\\Users\\recursor\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2012\\Projects\\CS3280\\Final Project\\IR\\ConsoleApplication2\\bin\\Debug\\ConsoleApplication2.vshost.exe.Config line 34)"}`

So it seems I have a situation where I can't use one, but the other doesn't support the invariant type. I don't know how to resolve this. I have been able to connect to the DB and the connection string work. I just search or modify any data using the entity framework.

I tried adding this, but it didn't help either.

```
   <system.data>
     <DbProviderFactories>
       <remove name="MySQL Data Provider"/>
       <add name="MySQL Data Provider"
          invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"
          description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL"
          type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
   </system.data>
```

**EDIT 1:**

Line 16 is `<providers>`.

Line 34 is `<DbProviderFactories>`

Comment: And where is **line 16 and 34**??

Comment: I just added that in my edit. Thanks

Comment: Have you edited your reference? Did you already added MySQL to your project?

Comment: Yes both MySql.data and MySql.data.entities both version 6.7.4.0 from NuGets

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently what I needed was

```
<clear />
```

instead of

```
<remove .. />
```